# Public Transit for Merfolk

Tags: transportation, merfolk, urban-fantasy

In an urban fantasy type world, how exactly would public transit work for merfolk?

Situation A: The merfolk are living in a big cross-species city that also has humanoids. For purposes of this question, I'm assuming they have specialized buses. How exactly would these buses work, and what would they look like?

Situation B: These merfolk live in the midway point of the ocean. Not the shallow coral reefs, but not the lightless abyss either. What could they use for their public transit, keeping in mind that they don't really have the ability to use things such as wheels and electricity. The bus would also span several 'levels' as there are no particular streets.

EDIT: The shallow merfolk can avoid water for about a week before drying out, so that isn't an issue. They are based off of dolphins, being able to breathe out of water and being able to hold their breath for 2 hours, though I am considering making it longer. They have no way of getting legs and currently, I have no real plans to put them in wheelchairs, though it is a possibility.

The city either has canals beside the sidewalks or tubes underneath the pathways, though I am leaning towards the former. The public transit needs to be able to get them to the merfolk-oriented areas and the public areas (such as city hall and a multitude of stores).

I'm assuming the bus could drop them off in a canal/tube entrance by the stops.

Comment: What kind of merfolk? Do they suffocate without water, or just slowly dehydrate? Or can they stay out of water for an extended period and thus could move around in wheelchairs?

Comment: It would depend on how your city looks and how it has been designed to accommodate merfolk already. If they have to use the footpaths like normal humans, will they dry out? does their tail change into feet? Or do they already have pathways they can swim along with currents, etc etc. You need to tell us more about your merfolk and the actual city design.

Comment: They're a shallow variant that I based off of dolphins and other sea-dwelling mammals. They can safely stay completely out of water for a week, so that isn't an issue. They also breathe oxygen and can hold their breath for about two hours underwater. However, they are so much more comfortable underwater and they have no way of getting legs. I am considering special wheelchair designs for them, but that's a topic for another question.

Comment: @Shadowzee i haven't decided between canals beside the sidewalks or tubes underneath, but i'm leaning towards the former. i'll try and edit my post to clarify

Comment: Where do you want them to go? Between water and water separated by land? Between land and land? What would they be using to get around on land between public transportation trips and would it come with them?

Comment: @JasonClyde i just edited it to specify. they are meant to go both between land and land and land and water

Comment: From the sounds of it, the city existed and then the merfolk came along. Since they can survive fine in the air, public transport isn't really much of an issue. You just keep the same public transport as always. The issue is how to effectively let the merfolk move around on land and water so that they can use public transport. I suggest they all get skateboards they can lie on.

Comment: What do yo mean by 'midway point of the ocean' ? Vertically through the water column or hortizontally across ? Either are still likely to be in darkness the Atlantic has an average depth of 3.6km and light does not penetrate below 1km, the MAR is 2km deep. Merfolk could probably only survive on continental shelf tyoe environments at the edge of oceans.

Comment: @Sarriesfan miday vertically. i haven't figured out details or done research yet, but the midway range that i'm using is quite broad.

Comment: This might be useful to read, https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/light_travel.html. The maximum  depth of continental shelf is around 150m after which there is a steep drop off to the abyssal plain below like a steep cliff. For merfolk there is pretty much either the continental that extends a relatively short distance from shore 80km or so at maximum or the of dark depths. The edge of shelves can be dangerous with turbidity flow events causing massive underwater landslides.

Comment: @Sarriesfan thank you, i'll definitely give it a read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have canals in and around your city for your aquatic cities, I'm picturing something along the lines of large ["Sea Scooters"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diver_propulsion_vehicle) like that used by human divers. They travel along predetermined routes, and are covered in handy holds that the merfolk can use to hitch a ride. They could be piloted, remote controlled, or autonomous. These could also work in ocean-based settlements.

For fast travel where there are no convenient canals, you could install a series of water slides for easy travel between different levels. For long flat stretches, water jets could be placed at intervals to give a needed speed boost.

Answer (score 5):

For a city like New York or Tokyo, the solution would be to repurpose the subway tunnels. Simply flood them with water (they will naturally flood if left unattended long enough) and the merpeople can swim comfortably to and from work.

Naturally, a system of tubes filled with still water will eventually become stagnant and nasty, being a health hazard for both the merpeople and the population on the surface, so the system will be attended by a maintenance staff who will ensure the tubes have clean water pumped in and oxygenated, while "dirty" water is flushed from the system.

This also provides the "public transit" part of the system, merpeople should be willing to pay to use the system since the currents induced in the tunnels will allow them to move much more rapidly and with less effort. Obviously there will be tubes going in each direction (or the flow is reversed between morning and evening rush hour), and building stations will be different from conventional subway practice.

Answer (score 2):

You could have feeder tubes. The feeder tubes are filled with water and open into watertight compartments in specialised buses or trains. For trains, you could have a regular train with the last couple of carriages being water filled for merpeople. The tubes connect to the bus or carriage, the passengers swim through and the door of both the tube and the public transport close.

If you have multi level buses then bus stops would need to drop down in the road so that normal passengers could get on with wheelchairs and the like on the upper deck of the bus while tubes underground connect with the lower deck of the bus which is water filled. Water filled transport seems the easiest way to get the merfolk on and off. 
You'd want your water deck on the bottom for a couple of reasons. If it leaked you'd not want the other passengers to get wet. That amount of water is heavy and would create a potential tipping hazard for the bus if on top.